# União de vetores, sem repetições em C

Tags: c, array

Segue o enunciado:

> Leia dois vetores de inteiros X e Y, cadao um com 5
>   elementos (assuma que o usuario nao informa elementos repetidos).
>   Calcule e mostre os vetores resultantes em cada caso abaixo:
>
> - Soma entre X e Y: soma de cada elemento de X com o elemento da mesma posicao em Y;
> - Produto entre X e Y: multiplicacao de cada elemento de X com o elemento da mesma posicao em Y;
> - Diferenca entre X e Y: todos os elementos de X que não exista em Y;
> - Interseccao entre X e Y: apenas os elementos que apareçam nos dois vetores;
> - Uniao entre X e Y: todos os elementos de X, e todos os elementos de Y que nao estao em X.

codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define TAM 5


int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

    int x[TAM], y[TAM], dif[TAM], c, c2, c3, n=0, uniao[TAM*2], aux=0;

    printf("Lendo o vetor X: \n");
    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        scanf("%d", &x[c]);
    }

    printf("\n\nLendo o vetor Y: \n");
    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        scanf("%d", &y[c]);
    }

    system("CLS");

    printf("Soma entre X e Y:\n");
    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        printf("%d\n", x[c] + y[c]);
    }

    printf("\n\nProduto entre X e Y:\n");
    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        printf("%d\n", x[c] * y[c]);
    }

    printf("\n\nDiferenca ente X e Y:\n");
    for(c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        for(c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){
            if(x[c] == y[c2])
                break;
        }

        if(c2==TAM){
            for(c3=0; c3<n; c3++){
                if(x[c] == dif[c])
                    break;
            }

            if(c3 == n)
                dif[n++] = x[c];
        }
    }

    for (c=0; c<n; c++){
        printf("%d\n", dif[c]);
    }

    printf("\n\nIntersecção entre X e Y:\n");
    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        for (c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){
            if (x[c] == y[c2]){
                printf("%d\n", x[c]);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nUnião entre X e Y:\n");
}
```

Eu não estou conseguindo fazer a uniao sem repetição de elementos.. alguem pode me ajudar? obrigada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode fazer dessa forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM 5

int verificar(int elemento,int vetor[],int tamanho);

int main()
{
int vet1[TAM];
int vet2[TAM];
int i;

for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
    printf("Digite o valor de vet1[%d]:",i);
    scanf("%d",&vet1[i]);
}

printf("\n\n");

for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
    printf("Digite o valor de vet2[%d]:",i);
    scanf("%d",&vet2[i]);
}

system("cls");

printf("Valores: ");
for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
    printf("%d ",vet1[i]);
}

for(i = 0 ; i < TAM ; i++){

    if(verificar(vet2[i],vet1,TAM)){
       printf("%d ",vet2[i]);
    }

}

return 0;
}


int verificar(int elemento,int vetor[],int tamanho){

int j;
for(j = 0; j < tamanho; j++){
    if(elemento == vetor[j]){
        return 0;
    }
}
 return 1;
}
```

No codigo acima,são impressos todos os valores do primeiro vetor, apos isso cada um dos valor do segundo vetor é comparado a todos os valores do primeiro vetor(nao função verificar), se nao houver repetição ocorre a impressão.

Comment: Seu algoritmo está em ordem quadrática. A estratégia precisa ser feita de maneira totalmente distinta para ser executado em ordem linearítmica